# Calligra font inside the math mode

Tags: fonts

I am trying to write symbols in Calligra font inside the math mode. Turn out it is not working. The code is given below.

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{calligra} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Calligra} \author{} \date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\calligra{Calligra font is not supported in the math mode}

\begin{equation}
    1 \leq \calligra{M}, \calligra{N} \geq 2 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Can any please why it is not working? Thanks!

Comment: `\calligra` is like `\ttfamily` and does not take an argument, the syntax in text is `{\calligra Calligra font is not supported in the math mode}` not `\calligra{Calligra font is not supported in the math mode}` The package does not declare math fonts, but you could use `\text{\calligra M}` in math

Comment: @ David Carlisle, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\calligra` is like `\ttfamily` and does not take an argument, the syntax in text is

```
{\calligra Calligra font is not supported in the math mode}
```

not

```
\calligra{Calligra font is not supported in the math mode}
```

The package does not declare math fonts, but you could use

```
\text{\calligra M}
```

in math